# Remove leading zero in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

The tables are:

```
Table A: tag_num (nvarchar(6))       Table B: tag_num (nvarchar(6))
------------------------------       ------------------------------
883                                  00883
```

The query:

```
select * from A test1 
inner join B test2 on test2.tag_num = test1.tag_num
```

return 0 rows due to the leading zeros in Table `B`.

How can I return the result

```
A.tag_num | B.tag_num
883       | 00883
```

even though Table `B` column contain leading zeros.

Which data type should I use?

Comment: are there only two `0` at the start or vary as per the value ?

Comment: If the tags doesn't contain spaces, one way would be to convert zeroes to spaces, left trim, then convert spaces back to zeroes: `REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(tag, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')`. Not convinced this is the best solution, nor very performant.

Comment: There's a few answers around casting this to an int to do the comparison. This is a great way to achieve what you're after if there are only ever numerics in your columns however as these are nvarchar(6) columns I'm suspicious that this is not always the case. Will there always be numbers in these columns? If so why aren't they just int's in the first place?

Comment: You should really fix your database instead of asking questions like this...

Answer (score 14):

You can cast the columns to `int`

```
select * 
from A test1 
inner join B test2 
      on cast(test2.tag_num as int) = cast(test1.tag_num as int)
```

Or better use `int` as data type in the table in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

you should [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the string to int and join on them

```
SELECT *
    FROM A AS test1 INNER JOIN B AS test2 
    ON CAST(test2.tag_num AS INT) = CAST(test1.tag_num AS INT)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep datatype of `NVARCHAR` and use `SUBSTRING` to remove leading zero in following:

```
select * from A test1 
inner join B test2 on test1.tag_num =
SUBSTRING(test2.tag_num, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', test2.tag_num+'.'), LEN(test2.tag_num))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid doing a type conversion on both sides, if you want any hope of using an index.  One method is to use `like`:

```
select *
from A inner join
     B
     on b.tag_num like '%' + a.tag_num;
```

However, this is too general, because the wildcards will match too many things.  Another approach would be to use `in`:

```
select *
from A inner join
     B
     on b.tag_num in (a.tag_num, '0' + a.tag_num, '00' + a.tag_num)
```

This has some hope of using an index on `b.tag_num.  Getting a sargable expression for`a.tag_num` is more challenging.

Comment: I realize it's old, but I am really interested in knowing your approach to a sargable expression if you don't mind.

Comment: @007 . . . You might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shorten version of casting:

```
select * from A test1 
inner join B test2 on 1*test2.tag_num = test1.tag_num
```

Multiplying by 1 will automatically cast result to `int`.

Comment: working solution for remove leading zero from varchar type during join operation